# Swift case statement

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, statements

I'm trying switch statements in Swift 3.0
With my code, I get A, no matter what my variable is. 
Why am I only getting A?

```
var grade = 45

switch grade {

    case (grade ..< 100):
        print("A")
    case (grade ..< 90):
        print("B")
    case (grade ..< 80):
        print("C")
    case (grade ..< 70):
        print("D")

    default:
        print("F. You failed")
}
```

Comment: If `grade` is less than 70, it's going to be less than 100. You might want to revisit the logic of your `case` statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A switch statement considers a value and compares it against several possible matching patterns. It then executes an appropriate block of code, based on the **first** pattern that matches successfully.

In your specific case try to use:

```
var grade = 45

switch grade {

case 90 ..< 100: //Numbers 90-99  Use 90...100 to 90-100
    print("A")
case (80 ..< 90): //80 - 89
    print("B")
case (70 ..< 80): // 70 - 79
    print("C")
case (0 ..< 70): // 0 - 69
    print("D")

default:
    print("F. You failed")//Any number less than 0 or greater than 99 

}
```

[check this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html)

> In contrast with switch statements in C and Objective-C, switch
>   statements in Swift do not fall through the bottom of each case and
>   into the next one by default. Instead, the entire switch statement
>   finishes its execution as soon as the first matching switch case is
>   completed, without requiring an explicit break statement. This makes
>   the switch statement safer and easier to use than the one in C and
>   avoids executing more than one switch case by mistake.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Switches are evaluated from top to bottom, so since the first test is met (`grade < 100`), the program will always return A. You can simply reverse the order of the cases. Generally, you want switch statements to go from most restrictive to least restrictive.

Comment: Your code causes crash when `grade` is greater than 70.